# run a function when routed to specific rout Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an application with angularjs what I need to do is to basically run some scripts when route is changed to a specific route I know that I can define a separate controller for each route. since, some routs are supposed to have shared data I shared a controller to between some of them

```
  formApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider

      .when('/firstUrl',{
          templateUrl : 'firstURL',
          controller : 'mainController'
       })

      .when('/secondURL' , {
          templateUrl : 'secondURL',
          controller : 'mainController'
       }) 

     }).run(function($rootScope, $location) {
         $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
         if ( signed_in == false ) {

             $location.path("/login");
          }
      });
  });
```

The above is my config code, 
MY QUESTION : I need to know if I can modify the code in the run() function, so that based on the route which user is redirected to some scripts are run.

or if this is not the right way to do that please correct me how do I have to solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to create at least one controller per route. It makes the code more manageble.
Then you can define an init function that runs when each controller loads.

To share data between controllers you need to create a service, which is the correct way to do it rather then sharing the same controller for multiple paths.

It will also give you way more flexibilitywhen developing.

### **Update**

**Example**
( Naming for example purposes only. Try to never do arrbitrary naming. )

**#Service**

```
angular.module('myService', [])

.factory('mSrv',[ function() {

    return {

        data: {
            'first_name': 'John',
            'last_name': 'Doe'
        }

    };

}])

;
```

**#Controller1**

```
angular.module('initMyCtrl1', ['myService'])

    .controller('InitMyCtrl1', function( $scope, mSrv ) {

        var initMyCtrl1 = function(){
            console.log('runs on controller load')
            console.log(mSrv.data);
        };

        initMyCtrl1();

    })

;
```

**#Controller2**

```
angular.module('initMyCtrl2', ['myService'])

    .controller('InitMyCtrl2', function( $scope, mSrv ) {

        var initMyCtrl2 = function(){
            console.log('runs on controller load')
            console.log(mSrv.data);
        };

        initMyCtrl2();

    })

;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try it and make it as the correct one as soon as it works :)